# how to schedule a task in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I am trying to set an alarm but i want that instead of playing the music
the app will read the todo list i have created.

I am using AVSpeechSynthesizer class for performing speaking functionality and it works fine but problem is,i am using Timer for scheduling a task and when the app goes into background the timer stops working

here is my code:

```
class Speaking : NSObject,AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

let speechSynthesizerObject = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-au")

override init() {
    super.init()
    speechSynthesizerObject.delegate = self
}

func speak(string: String) {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
    utterance.rate = 0.5
    utterance.voice = self.voice
    speechSynthesizerObject.speak(utterance)
}

func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
    print("all done")

}    
}
```

Alarm function

```
func setAlaram(){

    var date = self.appData.Alaram

    if(date < Date()){
        date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
    }

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    var component = calendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second], from: date)
    component.second = 0
    var modifiedDateTime = calendar.date(from: component)!

   var snooz = Timer(fireAt: modifiedDateTime, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(setSpeechRecognizeAsAlaram), userInfo: "first", repeats: false)
    RunLoop.main.add(snooz!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
 }
```

function that i want to fire when time collapse

```
 func setSpeechRecognizeAsAlaram( sender: Timer){
    guard let data = loadAppData() else{ return }
    self.appData = data

    let numberOfTodo = String(appData.ToDoList.count)


    var items = String()
    var counter = 1
    for item in appData.ToDoList {
        items += String(counter) + ", " + item + ". "
        counter += 1
    }

    let date = Date()
    let dateformat1 = DateFormatter()
    let dateformat2 = DateFormatter()
    dateformat1.dateStyle = .full
    dateformat2.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    var sentence = String()

    if(appData.ToDoList.count == 0){
        sentence = " Good Morning! It’s" + dateformat2.string(from: date) + "!. And it’s time to wake up!. I’m disappointed in you today. You forgot to add in new “TO-DO” items to your list."
    }
    else{
        sentence = "Good Morning! Its " + dateformat2.string(from: date) + "!. And its time to wake up. Today is " + dateformat1.string(from: date) + ". You have " + numberOfTodo + " items on your to-do list for the day. " + items + " Thats all!. I hope you have a productive day! "
    }
  let spk = Speaking()
    spk.speak(string: sentence)

}
```

any help will be appreciated

Thank's

Comment: You can’t execute arbitrary code at a scheduled time when your app is suspended.

Comment: What you're looking for is 
 UILocalNotification (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification), but I'm not sure you can run AVSpeechSynthesizer from there

Comment: Is tere any other way to do this ? . ULNotification will not allow to execute this function

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), Apples notes about how to run tasks in the background.

There is a section on *Getting the User’s Attention While in the Background*. There is an example of setting an alarm using a local notification.

From Apple's Website

---

<strike>**Listing 3-2**  Scheduling an alarm notification</strike>

```
- (void)scheduleAlarmForDate:(NSDate*)theDate
{
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray*    oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    // Clear out the old notification before scheduling a new one.
    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0)
        [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    // Create a new notification.
    UILocalNotification* alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (alarm)
    {
        alarm.fireDate = theDate;
        alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
        alarm.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
        alarm.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!";

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
    }
}
```

---

***UPDATE***

And of course, `UILocalNotification` is deprecated. The new replacement is [UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest).

Comment: I want AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak the script but how it is possible using UNNotification ?. I don't think my app lies in any category that apple allows to execute in background. any hacks ?

Comment: I would look for a way to write the sound to a file while the app is in the foreground. Then in the background play the sound file.